# How to iterate erasing multiple vectors from another vector using R?

Tags: r, erase

I need to erase different vector layers(shapefiles) using R, but I am not sure how to do it in a fast way.

I have 10 different shapefiles and a basemap (also shapefile) that I need to erase my vectors from (I need something equivalent to using the "difference" tool in QGIS).

I know how to do it manually, using the `ms_erase` tool, but I was wondering if there is an easy way of iterating this process:

```
output1 <- ms_erase(basemap, vector1)
output2 <- ms_erase(output1 , vector2)
output3 <- ms_erase(output2 , vector3)
```

I loaded the vectors using the `st_read` function, so their class in R is data.frame.

Comment: You may try first to rbind() all your erasing layers and the use that ms_erase or st_difference from sf

Comment: I would suggest the same as @ElioDiaz but you might want to `ms_dissolve` your combined files after `rbind` and before `ms_erase` if the shapes are complex or overlap. Installing Node.js and using `sys = TRUE` in `ms_erase` can also boost performance quite a bit if your first attempt crashes or takes too long.

Comment: I agree with @SandyAB; if your layers have different column names, `dplyr::bind_rows()` will work better

Comment: Which package does the `ms_erase` function come from? Why aren't you using the `st_difference` function from `sf`? Can you read all your shapefiles into a list of objects and loop over that list?

Answer (score 1):

I would read your 10 shapefiles into a list object so that you can easily combine them using `do.call`.

```
s <- do.call("rbind", lapply(list.files(getwd(), "shp$")[-1], st_read))
```

Note; if `s` does not result in an sf object you may have to wrap it in `st_as_sf`. The index "[-1]" is a illustration of removing a specific file. I am assuming that your "basemap" is in the same directory so, it should not be read into the list. You can figure out the position(s) of shapefiles to omit by just looking at the results of `list.files(getwd(), "shp$")`. Using indexing you can read in specific files eg., [c(1,3,5)] would read in the first, third and fifth files in the list.files vector.

Once you have the features that you want erased, then read in the base map and difference the features (not tested).

```
st_erase <- function(x, y) { st_difference(x, st_union(st_combine(y))) }
  b <- st_read(list.files(getwd(), "shp$")[1])
    e <- st_erase(b, s)
```